# Nginx does not pick up Environments from another services using Docker

Tags: reactjs, node.js, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file, I override the environments on frontend service. After I run up that docker-compose file, only http://localhost:3000/ can access those environments. Please see attachments below:

- Docker-compose file

  ```
  version: "3"
  networks:
    app_network:
      driver: bridge
  services:
    frontend:
      build: 
        context: "./Frontend"
        args:
          - REACT_APP_DEV_BE_URL=https://bugorfeature.tech/api/
      container_name: bof-frontend
      image: bof-frontend
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=production
        - REACT_APP_DEV_BE_URL=https://bugorfeature.tech/api/
        - REACT_APP_DEV_FE_URL=https://bugorfeature.tech/
      networks:
        - app_network
    backend:
      build: "./Backend"
      container_name: bof-backend
      image: bof-backend
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
      networks:
        - app_network
    webserver:
      build: "./nginx"
      container_name: bof-webserver
      image: bof-webserver
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - ./nginx/nginx.config:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      networks:
        - app_network
      depends_on:
        - frontend
        - backend
    certbot:
      image: certbot/certbot
      container_name: certbot
      volumes:
        - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
        - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  ```
- Nginx config

  ```
  events {}

  http {
      server_tokens off;
      charset utf-8;
       # always redirect to https
      server {
          listen 80 default_server;
          server_name _;
          location / {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
              index index.html index.htm;
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          }

          location /api/ {
              rewrite /api/(.*) /$1  break;
              proxy_pass http://backend:4000;  # Use the service name defined in Docker Compose
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- After docker-compose up

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0Wc.png)

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0HX9.png)

How can localhost:80 of Nginx access those environments??